# Verificar se input file esta com arquivo ou não

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

Estou precisando fazer uma validação no campo file, caso o mesmo não tenha anexo me mostre uma mensagem na tela obrigando a anexar, já tentei algumas alternativas e não consegui.

```
<div class="form-group" id="inputOculto">
      <input name="arquivo" type="file"  class="form-control-anexo"  input/> 
</div>
```

Esse campo só aparece se no assunto eu seleciono a opção Trabalhe Conosco.

No js esta assim:

```
// Contact form com anexo e sem anexo
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data;
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    data = $("#main-contact-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            if ($('#mySelect').val() == 'Trabalhe Conosco')
            {
               if ($('#arquivo').val() == null)
               {
                  alert("É Obrigatório Anexar Seu Currículo!" );    
               }
            }
            else
            {
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Enviando Mensagem...</p>').fadeIn() );
            }
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Mensagem enviada. O mais breve possível retornaremos o contato.</p>').delay(9000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('#arquivo').files.length === 0) {
   alert("É Obrigatório Anexar Seu Currículo!" )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Atribua um `id` e um atributo `required` ao seu `<input type="file">` e verifique se é valido...caso não tenha um arquivo, não será valido.

Podes verificar se a entrada é (ou não) valida usando `validity.valid`...caso não seja então podes lançar seu alerta e observar um evento de mudança.

```js
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
let file = document.getElementById('fileupload')
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            if ( file.validity.valid ) {
                //... ok [send]
            } else {
                // observe file change
                file.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
                    if ( evt.target.result.length > 0 ) {
                        //... ok
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }).done(function(data)  {
        //...
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="main-contact-form" action="#">
    <div class="form-group" id="inputOculto">
        <input id="fileupload" name="arquivo" type="file" required> 
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Você pode também definir o tipo de arquivo com o attributo `accept=""`

Answer (score 1):

Se você acrescentar o atributo "required" a tag input, o próprio navegador já irá validar a obrigatoriedade do campo:

```
<div class="form-group" id="inputOculto">
    <input name="arquivo" type="file" class="form-control-anexo" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem problemas no seu código:

Erro de sintaxe no `input`:

```
<input name="arquivo" type="file"  class="form-control-anexo"  input/>
                                                                 ↑
```

O correto seria:

```
<input name="arquivo" type="file" class="form-control-anexo">
```

Você está chamando o campo `file` por um `id` que não existe:

```
if ($('#arquivo').val() == null)
          ↑
```

Você poderia inserir um `id` ao campo `file`, mas não é necessário, porque você pode pegar pelo `name`:

```
if ($('input[name="arquivo"]').val() == null)
```

Mas você ainda pode fazer desta forma:

```
if(!$('input[name="arquivo"]').val()){
```

O `!` irá retornar `true` caso o campo `file` esteja vazio.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   if(!$('input[name="arquivo"]').val()){
      alert("É Obrigatório Anexar Seu Currículo!" );
   }else{
      alert("Arquivo anexado!" );
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main-contact-form">
<input name="arquivo" type="file" class="form-control-anexo" />
<br>
<button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: De nada amigo! Se achou a resposta melhor, pode marcar ✓ e/ou dar um voto positivo, se desejar. Obg!